# Can a process load two DLLs with exactly the same name?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dll, loadlibrary

Help interpreting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications):

> ### Dynamic-Link Library Search Order
>
> ...
>
> If a DLL with *the same module name is already loaded* in memory, the
>   system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to
>   the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. *The system does
>   not search for the DLL*.

Note: Multiple DLLs with the same name basically *is* a bad idea, this is just to get a better picture.

Consider:

```
...\x\foo.exe
...\x\a\bar.dll ~ no further dependencies
...\x\b\bar.dll ~ no further dependencies
```

Is it possible to load both of these `bar.dll` into `foo.exe` with explicit load library calls? *And* where/how is this documented and supported (otherwise I'd just try it.)

That is, will the following reliably work on Windows7+ :

```
// Load using full path:
HANDLE a_mod = LoadLibrary(L"...\x\a\bar.dll");
HANDLE b_mod = LoadLibrary(L"...\x\b\bar.dll");
// now use moth DLLs ...
```

Comment: ComCtl32.dll has existed in two versions since WinXP and you will sometimes see both loaded in a process. They exist in two different activation contexts but it is the most common case you will see in the wild.

Comment: @Anders - ah yes Activation Contexts. The road to horribly documented insanity :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Desktop applications can control the location from which a DLL is loaded by specifying a full path, using DLL redirection, or by using a manifest. **If none of these methods are used,** the system searches for the DLL at load time as described in this section.
>
> Before the system **searches** for a DLL, it checks the following:
>
> - If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.

So, the clause you're worried about doesn't apply when a full path is provided.

Comment: The Remarks section for [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also has a clause "If *lpFileName* does not include a path and there is more than one loaded module with the same base name and extension, the function returns a handle to the module that was loaded first.", which would be quite meaningless if it were not possible to load multiple DLLs with the same filename.

Comment: @Quietust - ah I read that too, but forgot to mention it. It was actually one of the triggers for this question, as it seemed contradictory :-)

Comment: There you go. The right highlighting can resolve the trickiest issues ;-)